# JMeter preferring Negotiate over NTLM

Tags: jmeter, ntlm, loadrunner, negotiate

We have an application where it is enabled with Windows Authentication where it has Negotiate and NTLM in the provider module. It seems that Jmeter is preferring to send the request using the Negotiate and is failing whereas when tried from LoadRunner, we see that it is always sending as NTLM and it passes from there.

Has anyone come across this kind of situation? If yes, how can we force Jmeter to use NTLM authentcation rather than Negotiate?

Thanks for help.

Comment: What Dmitri wrote. You have to do a bunch of configurations instead of having it work for you out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

JMeter doesn't "prefer" anything, it depends on the [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) configuration which **you** have to perform.

Your test should implement real user behavior, not LoadRunner behaviour, if real browser performs [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)) authentication - you need to do this and vice versa.

---

To force JMeter to use NTLM just make sure not to select `KERBEROS` mechanism, use `BASIC_DIGEST`.

Check out [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter/) article for more details if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have successfully used authorization manger when port was 443 or 80. In my other scenario, the url has also port (not typical 80 or 443) in it with the url seems be like - http://helloworld.server.com:51527/abcrestofurl.aspx . So what should I pass in the authorization manager. I tried putting http://helloworld.server.com:51527 in the url section of auth manager but it does not work and I get 401 error with basic_digest. Server has windows auth with NTLM as provider listing. Any suggestions.